# JMeter cannot connect to local IP

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run JMeter with distibuted mode, on one VM and my local machine. I am able to execute the tests through the command line with the VM but it fails when attempting to use my local host of 127.0.0.1 how can I properly configure JMeter to run tests on my local and the VM? In JMeter properties I have added the VM IP address comma delimited to the

```
"remote_hosts=127.0.0.1,VM_IP_HERE"
```

and I have the jmeter.server running on the VM. Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

> Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Are you running your tests from your localhost? As in your app is hosted on the same machine as the JMeter instance is running on?